# Salesforce : New Event and New Task link is not showing in Opportunity kanban view

Tags: salesforce, kanban

Salesforce - Activity option not available on Kanban view in lightning. Where it says No Open Activities, user should be able to have 'New Task/New Event' hyperlink.

When in opportunity kanban view, you should be able to hover over the orange warning triangle (warning is for no future activity scheduled for that opportunity), and create an event from the pop up window that appears.

Need assistance setting this up. Can anyone let me know where this setting is? There is no documentation online.